# DllImport signature error

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have an DLL file named `WD_SDK.dll` (it go with an `SDK.h` file).

I open the `SDK.h` and I see:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK * VideoCaptureCB_Ptr)(PVOID pContext, BYTE * apData[3],
VideoSampleInfo_T * pVSI);

typedef struct _VideoSampleInfo_T
{
    ULONG   idFormat; // 
    ULONG   lSignalState;
    int     nLen; // not used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
    int     nWidth;
    int     nHeight;
    int     anPitchs[3]; // only used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
    ULONG   dwMicrosecsPerFrame; // 1000*1000/FPS
    ULONG   field;
    int     iSerial;

} VideoSampleInfo_T;

WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(HANDLE hChannel, PVOID pContext, VideoCaptureCB_Ptr pCB);
```

I want to call the `WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB` in C#. So I use the DllImport to declare it in C#. It look like this:

```
[DllImport("WD_SDK.dll", EntryPoint = "_WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB@12", ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern int WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(IntPtr hChannel,  object pContext, VideoCaptureCB_Ptr pCB);
```

Then I re-declare the C++ struct and CALLBACK in C# like this:

```
public delegate void VideoCaptureCB_Ptr(IntPtr pContext, byte[] apData, VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VideoSampleInfo_T
{
    public uint idFormat;
    public uint lSignalState;
    public int nLen; // not used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
    public int nWidth;
    public int nHeight;
    public int[] anPitchs; // only used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
    public uint dwMicrosecsPerFrame; // 1000*1000/FPS
    public uint field;
    public int iSerial;

}
```

And one delegate implement

```
public static void HandleVideoStatic(IntPtr pContext, byte[] apData, VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI)
{
}
```

When i run my  code :

```
WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i],  m_aMediaHandler[i], HandleVideoStatic);
```

THe program show me an error `does not match the unmanaged target signature.`

I thinks encountered problem with the `PVOID pContext`, I changed it to object `pContext`. But I have to pass the `m_aMediaHandler[i]` (It's an instance of a class not a pointer) to it, the error raised " .."invalid agruments"

P/S: The `WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB` call in C++

```
WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i], &m_aMediaHandler[i], HandleVideoStatic);
```

Comment: Use depends.exe to see if the exported name is mangled.

Comment: Can you please use "dumpbin.exe" to list the definitions exported by your dll. `dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS WD_SDK.dll`. Please update the question with the output you get.

Comment: I have updated information from dumpbin.exe please check it and help me. THanks in advance, very much.

Comment: That should answer your question...

Comment: It is no mangled. But I still don't know how my code wrong.

Comment: Of course it is mangled... Set `EntryPoint="_WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB@12"` or use ordinals. Note: It seems you will have to call "WD_InitSDK" too. A better option might be to use "managed c++" here.

Comment: `[DllImport("WD_SDK.dll", EntryPoint="_WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB@12", 
        ExactSpelling = true)]`

Comment: I have called the WD_InitSDK(). After add new DLLimport attribute It show this error :) 

Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'Camera!Camera.Form1::WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: Could you guys help me check my code to make it match the signature with the DLL. I thinks encountered problem with the PVOID pContext, I changed it to object pContext. But i have to pass the m_aMediaHandler[i] ( It's an instance of a class not a pointer )  to it, the error raised " .."invalid agruments"

Comment: What happens when you change `object pContext` to `IntPtr pContext`?

Comment: Also change all `int`s in VideoSampleInfo_T to `System.Int16`

Comment: If i change from object pContext to IntPtr pContext. I show error "invalid agrument" becase I pass to it an class instance...... P/S: ___________In C++ code the method look like this one "WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i], &m_aMediaHandler[i], HandleVideoStatic);"

Comment: Not sure here but put this attribute on your delegate `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)] public delegate void VideoCaptureCB_Ptr(IntPtr pContext, byte[] apData, VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI);`, keep pContext as `IntPtr` and try `ref IntPtr pContext`.

Comment: Among other things, you didn't declare the number of elements in `anPitchs`.

Comment: @Abhi. It work. But i encoutered new problem. My HandleVideoStatic is not work :( I put an debugging point in HandleVideoStatic() body. But the VS debugging dont stop at the point.

Comment: Do this. `//At Class level
public delegate void VideoCaptureCB_Ptr(IntPtr pContext, byte[] apData, VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI);
GCHandle gchCallback;`
Then calling your unmanaged function:
`VideoCaptureCB_Ptr callbackDelegate = HandleVideoStatic;
IntPtr callbackPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callbackDelegate);
gchCallback = GCHandle.Alloc(callbackDelegate);
WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i],  m_aMediaHandler[i], callbackPtr);`

Comment: May I send you my SDK and  C++ sample source code. You help me convert it to C# ?